# update SQL row with Javascript in it

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, datatable

i want to update the below entire code into SQL row as row data but because of the special characters in javascript it is not letting me .

[script]document.getElementById('form');document.getElementById('form2');[/script] [script]document.getElementById('form');document.getElementById('form2');[/script]

Comment: `encodeSpecialCharacters` or something? [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: yes, i want to insert complete code in that as text

Comment: Use query parameters with a prepared statement. Special characters in data don't matter if you separate the query from the data.

Comment: *i want to insert complete code in that as text* https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=095aa2f9e525e544258f8d9a83e564c3